# ext-zend-opcache * error while installing pimcore by composer

Tags: php, pimcore

Facing issue of zend-opcache while installing Pimcore by composer.
zend-opcache is already enabled and showing in PHPINFO.

Please find error message following

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for amnuts/opcache-gui 3.2.1 -> satisfiable by amnuts/opcache-gui[3.2.1].
- amnuts/opcache-gui 3.2.1 requires ext-zend-opcache * -> the requested PHP extension zend-opcache is missing from your system.

Problem 2
- amnuts/opcache-gui 3.2.1 requires ext-zend-opcache * -> the requested PHP extension zend-opcache is missing from your system.
- pimcore/pimcore v6.9.0 requires amnuts/opcache-gui ^3.0.1 -> satisfiable by amnuts/opcache-gui[3.2.1].
- Installation request for pimcore/pimcore v6.9.0 -> satisfiable by pimcore/pimcore[v6.9.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/php.ini
- /usr/lib/mw/php/7.4.3/etc/conf.d/mods.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: "zend-opcache is already enabled and showing in PHPINFO"—how are you checking PHP info? PHP often has multiple configuration files that apply in different cases, e.g. one for Apache and another for the command-line. Your error points to two files and suggests running `php --ini` to see which files are being used.

Comment: For phpinfo, I just created a php file with phpinfo function and run it on browser.

Comment: Right, so that's a different PHP and it probably uses a different configuration file. As the error suggests, run `php --ini` on the command line to see what config file you should use. Then make sure to enable the module in _that_ file.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `phpinfo()` uses the config of the `fpm` process from the webserver. This is a different php config file then the one that is used for `php` commands on the command line.

Did you check output of the `php --ini` command?
The `/etc/php/php.ini` file should reference the `ext-zend-opcache` extension.